# IIS 7.5 dynamicCompressionLevel setting has no impact

Tags: iis-7.5, compression

I have a Web.API app with an action that is sending a 5MB json result (for reasons outside the scope of this question).  Initially we weren't compressing json results for this server.

I added  to the  section under "httpCompression", and now Chrome is showing that file being compressed to 1011KB.  When I used 7zip (with gzip compression) at the fastest setting, I compressed the same text down to 270KB, so I was hoping for a better compression from IIS.

I tried setting the dynamicCompressionLevel to different values

```
<scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" dynamicCompressionLevel="9"/>
```

but Chrome is showing a compressed size of 1011KB with every setting.  I know I'm updating the correct applicationHost.config file because every time I make changes to this my app pool recycles.

I'm really at a loss here..what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

AHH!

I had to actually restart the IIS Server...the app pool recycle wasn't enough.